# Font installation in LaTeX: otftotfm mktexupd failed

Tags: fonts, miktex, otftotfm

I'm using `otftotfm` tools with a Windows/MiKTeX 2.8 installation, when I run something like

```
otftotfm -a --verbose -e ec  -fkern -fliga Ubuntu-R.ttf T1--Ubuntu--Regular
```

I receive an error message that the command `mktexupd` could not be found. It seems to be some  dependency that's not present under MiKTeX.

Is it possible to use the `otftotfm` tools with MiKTeX?

Comment: First: The Use a deprecated version should be well justified, because in general this is cosidered as off-topic here, cf. http://miktex.org/releases. And no, there is no `mktexupd` in MiKTeX. You should download a TeX Live for Windows and use it portable, when you want to stick with MiKTeX. BTW: In TeX Live otftotfm tools are alreay included.

Answer (score 1):

I did use the lcdf type tools a few years ago – mainly `otfinfo` and `cfftot1` with a MiKTeX system, downloading the w32tex version and putting it anywhere in my hard disk. It was to be able to use the MinionPro package, but these applications are independent of any TeX system.

In your case, `otftotfm` of course is linked to TeX, and `mktexupd` is a script that uses `kpathsea`, which does not exist in MiKTeX, as far I know. Moreover, running otftotfm --help specifies that it can convert the metrics of an opentype font to .tfm's, but only for postscript flavour open type fonts – and yours has a truetype flavour, so I'm not sure at all that you could obtain tfm's.

Maybe you can try to install, parallel to MiKTeX, a minimalistic TeX Live system, including the LCDF Type Tools.

Comment: It works fine with many `.ttf` fonts, including `Ubuntu-R.ttf`. The `.ttf` extension is often misleading...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run it without the `-a` option which tries to automatically install the font as well as generating the needed files. This works fine with `Ubuntu-R.ttf`. `otftotfm` will not need `mktexupd` to generate the files since that script is designed to update the file database `ls-R`. So it should work fine. You will just need to place the files yourself since you are using MiKTeX.

Comment: I'm quite happy to learn that: It will allow me to install the latest version of MinionPro (and MyriadPro).